# jQuery selecting first empty required field

Tags: jquery

```
$(":input[required][value='']:first").focus()
```

So I have been using this jQuery select to move to the next required input box in my form that is blank. When I tried to update my jQuery library from v1.7.2 to 1.11.1 or 2.1.1 this no longer works.

I tried rewriting the select statement several other ways such as :

```
$(":input[value='']").filter("[required]:first").focus();
```

It seems to get hung up on the "required" part of the select statement.

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please?

Comment: Also please post the relevant HTML *as saved from the browser* (not source). Any preceding error in the page will stop your code running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should filter as it to support newer jq version:

```
$(":input[required]").filter(function(){
    return !this.value;
}).first().focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var required = $("input[type='text'][required]");
var empty = required.filter(function() { return this.value === ""; });
var first = empty.filter(':first');

first.focus();
```

(Off course you can do it in just one line, it was jus for the sake ok explanation).

[Check this out on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qiworehope/4/edit?html,css,js,output)

I think it works as you expected.